# Wrapper or divs within it won't go to the bottom of certain pages on my site

Tags: html, css, image, wrapper

On my site, all the pages of text, stay within the wrapper which goes to the bottom of the page. For some reason on a page with images, the wrapper doesn't go to the bottom, nor does the div which holds the images.

Here is the html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Just Joel</title>
    <link href="../CSS/JJ.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../CSS/grogrotesque.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="../js/slideshow.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="../../../CSS/JJ.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapperfull">

    <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="../../../Images/Header.png" width="379" height="99" alt="Just Joel Header"></a>
    </div><!-- end header div -->

    <div class="navigation">
    <div class="menu-holder">
    <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="../../index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../../about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="../../print.html">Print</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../../branding.html">Branding</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../../photography.html">Photography</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../blog.html">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../inspired.html">Inspired</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     <!-- menu-holder end -->
    </div><!-- end navigation div --> 


    <div class="blog-container">
    <div id="sidebarwrapper">

<div id="sidebar">


    <h1>TREE TOP NEWS</h1>
     <br>
     <p>Tree Top News is a publcation produced through Highgate Woods, a heritage woodland in London</p>

     <p>I produced the publication two years running, capturing the amazing nature and wildlife around he wood. I was responsible for rt direction, design and print.</p>


    </div><!--sidebar!-->
    </div>


<div class="project">

   <img src="../../../Images/Tree Top News/P7158702.jpg" alt="Tree Top" class="image" height="378" width="580">
   <img src="../../../Images/Tree Top News/P7158703.jpg" alt="Tree Top" class="image" height="378" width="580">
   <img src="../../../Images/Tree Top News/P7158711.jpg" alt="Tree Top" class="image" height="378" width="580">
     <img src="../../../Images/Tree Top News/P7158701.jpg" alt="Tree Top" class="image" height="378" width="580">
    <img src="../../../Images/Tree Top News/Tree Top News 2010-6.jpg" alt="Tree Top" class="image" height="378" width="580">

    </div>

    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
    #wrapperfull {
min-height: 100%;
width: 1050px;
border: none;
margin-top: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
position: relative; /* for the absolute positioned footer */
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
padding-top: 0.1px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 30px;
    }

    #head {
height: 100px;
width: 1050px;
border: none;
margin: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
position: fixed;
    }

    #header {
height: 135px;
width: 1045px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-top: 0px;
    }

    #footer {
position: absolute;
width: 1050px;
height: 85px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0px;
margin-bottom: 150px;
    }

    .footer-style {
padding: 40px;
    }

    h1 {
font-family: "geogtq md";
color: #00BDE5;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-top: 35px;
    }

    h1:hover {
color: #007889;
font-size: 25px;
    }

    h2 {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #00BDE5;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
    }

    h2:hover {
color: #007889;
font-size: 25px;
    }

    p {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #01778B;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: justify;
    }

    img {
float: right;
    }

    html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
height: 100%;
    }

    body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
height: 100%;
background-image: url(../Images/stripe_70d2cce6f1e8675c4b38e18625444054.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
    }

    /* because of the box model anong with the height and set width, you'll want to have padding, border, and margin set to 0. Auto left and right margins are ok for centering. */


    .container {
   height: 100%;
   width: 1050px;
   margin-top:120px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .heading {
height: 90px;
width: 750px;
float: left;
margin-top: 70px;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-bottom: 35px;
margin-left: auto;
    }

    .blog-container {
   min-height: 100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 170px;
margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .work-container {
     min-height: 100%;
     width: 585px;
     margin-top: 70px;
     background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .slideshow {
width: 900px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
margin-top: 25px;
    }

    ul.slideshow li {
position: absolute;
left: -2px;
top: -9px;
display: inline;
    }

    .navigation {
height: 150px;
width: 600px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .menu-holder ul {
height: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    .menu-holder ul li {
position: relative;
float: left;
line-height: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .menu-holder ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
 float: left;
 color: #000;
    }
    .menu-holder ul li a {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
display: block;
color: #00BDE5;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .menu-holder ul li a:hover {
color: #007985;
    }

    .menu-holder ul li ul {
    float: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: -10px;
    margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .menu-holder ul li ul:hover {
    display: block;
    }
    .menu-holder ul li ul li {
     position: static;
         float: none;
         display: inline;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
 margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    }

    a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    ul {
    font-size: 15px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
margin-right: 40px;
    }

    ul li, ul li ul li {
display: inline;
position: relative;
float: left;
color: #00BDE5;
    }

    li ul {
   display: none;
   width: 450px;
margin-right: 20px;
    }

    ul ul li a {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
     margin-right: 15px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     color: #00BDE5;
margin-right: 20px;
    }

    li:hover ul {
    display: inline;
     position: absolute;    
    }

    li:hover li {
    float: none;
     font-size: 15px;
     margin-top:3px;
    }

    .services1 a {
     font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #00BDE5;
    float: left;
     list-style-type: none;
    }

    a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00BDE5;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
    }

    a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #007889;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
    }

    /* Thumb size 230 x 150 px */

    .work_thumbs {
width:1000px;
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
float: left;
    }

    .work_thumbs li {
margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
float: left;
display: inline;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
overflow: hidden;
    }

    .work_thumbs li a {
float: inherit;
display: block;
width: 230px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #00BDE5;
height: 180px;
border: 1px solid #02BDE5;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: centre;
font-size: 12px;
    }

    .work_thumbs li .type {
color: #01BDE6;
    }

    .work_thumbs li a:hover {
background-color: #ceeef6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #02BDE5;
text-decoration: none;
color: #007789;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: centre;
    } 

    .work_thumbs li .thumb {
margin-bottom: 15px;
display:block
    }

    .project {
width: 580px;
height: 1000px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 100px;
left: auto;
background-color: #fff;
    }

    .single .header {
position:static
    }

    .single #sidebar a {
color:#000;
    }

    .single #sidebar a:hover {
color:#4f4f4f
    }       

    .image {
margin: 0px;
padding-bottom:50px;
    }

    /* Set fixed top margin */ 

    #sidebar {
width: 273px;
height: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 165px;
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
color:#00C0EE;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: fixed;
color: #007789;
font-size: 15px;
    }

    #sidebar h1 {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
color: #00C0EE;
    }

    #sidebar p {
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #007789;
height: 100%;
    }

    #sidebarwrapper {
right: 822px;
position: absolute;
width: 205px;
height: 200px;
top: 248px;
    }

    * {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
    }

    #page-wrap {
width: 600px;
margin: 15px auto;
position: relative;
    }

    #sidebar ul {
background: #EEE;
padding: 10px;
    }

    li {
float: left;
display: inline;
    }

    #main {
width: 700px;
float: left;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Lze/

Comment: use jsfiddle.net please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a clearfix to clear the floats contained within. This forces the div containing the floated images take up that space instead of collapse into itself:

```
.project:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

Or just add it to `div:after` instead

Comment: Thanks so much, been bugging me for a while, lifesaver